# Adding divs into html and array and if delete, they need to be removed from html and array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to add an div to my html page:

```
$('.block:last').after(
    '<div class="block">' + blabla +
    '<span class="remove"><button type="button"></button></span></div>'
)
```

I use this because it add me an new div with className Block after the last found div>block.

Works perfect. But need this also in an array and ofcourse removing it also from array in case of delete.

This is code to remove the div block (all added divs are inside in div optionBox):

```
$('.optionBox').on('click','.remove',function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

deleting div works perfect too
Now , how to have this exactly data also in an array?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us your array code also.

Comment: Carsten , i dont have and clue , i was thinking for an array in array. so i can save it in an mySql. quotation[htmlcode][price result]

Comment: you should give some unique id and save it in array which you can delete also while deleting div

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar unique id will not help him when he try to retrieve the data how can he knows which id for which block?  .. He should provide the complete event which he used to add the new block , from where `blabla` comes from , which kind of data he needs to save in the array and he needs the array of all the blocks or just the new added ones? .. Finally no need for add/remove array 1- each block needs to have saved unique (number) 2-use `data` attribute in each block with this saved (number)  3- use `map()` and `join()` `.block` with data attribute numbers after add new block and onremove

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
var $elementToAdd = $('<div class="block">' + blabla +
    '<span class="remove"><button type="button"></button></span></div>');
yourArray.push($elementToAdd);
var indexInArray = yourArray.indexOf($elementToAdd);
$elementToAdd.data('index-in-array',indexInArray);
$('.block:last').after($elementToAdd);
```

And to remove that element:

```
$('.optionBox').on('click','.remove',function() {
    yourArray.splice($(this).parent().data('index-in-array'),1);
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: OP states that `deleting div works perfect too Now` so how is your answer solving the problem he has with the array?

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan Awan , yes this is the same as my code above(only shorter) , but what is the best approach to have an array with the same divs added/deleted?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Sorry, My bad. Please see the edited answer. I hope it solves your problem

Comment: @MuhammadHannanAwan : 'index-in-array' This part i dont understand.

Comment: 'index-in-array' is the index of element in the array you are storing the elements. This is used to delete the element in the array also. we are saving it as data attribute of the element so when user clicks on the close button you have the index of that element in the click event. simply remove the element from DOM and from the array as well using that index

Comment: Array.prototype.push() returns the new length not the index

Comment: @AndTheGodsMadeLove Thanks for pointing this out. I have fixed that in the new edit.